# opencv color image to greycode conversion error

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

i started on a project which inputs 2 images and detect the keypoints using sift and then checking the similarity of the 2 images

i actually completed the project without converting the image files to greycode but later i understood that converting images to grey code and then comparing gives more accurate results

so i wrote the code to convert the image to greycode 
but i am facing a problem

```
import cv2
import easygui
import sys
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

print "image 1 :",sys.argv[1]
print "image 2 :",sys.argv[2]
print "******** comparing images please wait *********"
file1=sys.argv[1]
file2=sys.argv[2]

img1 = cv2.imread(file1,0)#queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread(file2,0)#trainImage
gray_image1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray_image2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

i am getting an error

```
image 1 : taj1.jpg
image 2 : taj2.jpg
******** comparing images please wait *********
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /root/opencv-3.3.0/opencv-3.3.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 10638
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image_similarity.py", line 14, in <module>
    gray_image1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /root/opencv-3.3.0/opencv-3.3.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:10638: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

how can i resolve it 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert it, if you load it as you do.

```
img1 = cv2.imread(file1,0)#queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread(file2,0)#trainImage
```

Second parameter=0 means you load it as gray scale image.

Comment: @steventhomas Didn't you read the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread)?

Comment: sorry guys , it was my mistake not reading the documentation , sorry for wasting your time